# Generic command routing in MassTransit

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

How do i install a generic endpoint routing for sending commands in MassTransit?

We are just prototyping MassTransit and i wish to develop a base library, so our implementers can solely focus on business cases.
In this base library i want to install a generic routing for the commands. Eg:
there is a command defined in a library named "FancyService.Contracts.DoSomethingCommand". Where ever this command gets send, it has to be routed to the "FancyService"-Exchange/-Queue.

By googleing i found the "EndpointConvention" class, but i'm unsure, how to override the default behaviour.

In summary, i don't want our implementers to write this code:

```cs
    Bus.Instance
        .GetEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/FancyService"))
        .Send(new Message { });
```

But just write:

```cs
    Bus.Instance
        .Send(new Message { });
```

---

**Edit:**

Just found a workaround. Get all command types and call "EndpointConvention.Map(Uri)" by reflection. But is this the way to go?

Comment: When Conductor is available in v6, it will provide automatic service discovery for request clients. But I'm concerned that you're creating an abstraction for an abstraction (MassTransit), and that always leads to suffering in the end.

Comment: Not an abstract for an abstraction, but a convenience dll, where everything ist automatically wired (incl. di-container, logging, the bus system, automapper, fluentvalidation, and so on...)

Comment: Makes sense, there is some useful work in MassTransit.Host that may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but MassTransit is out for now ;( My workmates found Rebus easier to grasp...